# Change for-loop to a while

Tags: java, while-loop

How can I change the following code to while-loop?

```java
for (int i = 12; i < 40; i += 14) {
    for (int j = 30; j > 10; j -= 9) {
        System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
    }
}
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```java
public class WhileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 12;
        int j = 10;
        while (i <= 40) {
            while (j <= 30) {
                System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that your first code includes the magic numbers 9 and 14 and your second example *doesn't* should be your first clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you looking for:

```java
int i = 12;
while (i < 40) {
    int j = 30;
    while (j > 10) {
        System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
        j -= 9;
    }
    i += 14;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is working fine, int j = 30; the place of this var solve it.

Answer (score 1):

To convert ANY `for` loop into a `while` loop, you have to understand the anatomy of both loops. In general, both loops are constructed as follows:

***for-loop***

```
for (loop counter initialization; break condition; counter increment/decrement) {
    body of loop
}
```

***while-loop***

```
while (break condition) {
    body of loop
}
```

The only thing missing in the `while` loop is the counter initialization and the counter decrement/increment. Typically, when you require loop counters, you will use a `for` loop. When you don't require a loop counter, you will use a `while` loop. BUT, that is not a rule enforced by the language. You can do something like this to use a `while` loop with a counter variable:

```
int counter = 0;
while (break condition) {
    body of loop
    counter++;
}
```

Or, if you want to use a `for` loop without a counter:

```
for (;break condition;) {
    body of loop
}
```

Or even something crazier like this:

```
for (;;) {
    body of loop
    if (break condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

OBVIOUSLY, the best thing is to use the loops for their intended purpose: for-loops when loop counters are required and while-loops when they are not.

Based on the information here, you should be able to see that:

```
for (int i = 12; i < 40; i += 14) {
    for (int j = 30; j > 10; j -= 9) {
        System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
    }
}
```

Should translate to:

```
int i = 12;

while (i < 40) {
    int j = 30; // initializing this outside the outer `while` is a logic error
    while (j > 10) {
        System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
        j -= 9;
    }
    i += 14;
}
```

The easiest way to achieve this conversion is to start from the inside out. Meaning, go to the innermost loop, convert it following my suggestion, and work your way out. No matter how nested your loop is, you should be able to convert any `for` into a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here. First, you need to retain the same condition in the `for` and `while` loops. Second, you need to use the same increment the `for` loop uses, not just a `++` call. Third, you aren't initializing `j` like it is in the loop, and the initialization should be done **inside** the outer loop:

```java
public class WhileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 12;
        while (i < 40) {
            int j = 30;
            while (j > 10) {
                System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
                j -= 9;
            }
            i += 14;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Initializing `j` outside the outer loop is a logic error.

Comment: @hfontanez good catch! edited and fixed

Comment: When I used to teach, I would tell my students to always start from the inside out. When we work outside in, it is easy to make this mistake of initializing all counter variables outside the outer loop. That's why I posted the full explanation on how to tackle this type of problem rather than just answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code to your problem where you aren't seeting up again the value of `j` to it's default value,

```
public class WhileExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 12;
    int j = 30;
    while (i < 40) {
      while (j > 10) {
        System.out.println(i + "+" + j + "=" + (i + j) + "");
        j -= 9;
      }
      i += 14;
      j = 30;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Initializing loop counter `j` outside the outer loop is a logic error. To mitigate this logic error, you re-initialize the counter at the end. This is totally unnecessary. There is a simple formula for this conversion. See my post if you have any questions.

Comment: Got your point @hfontanez, Thankyou for this valuable information.